# What can I deduct while assisting in caring for elderly relatives that do not live with me?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction

I provide all transportation to medical appointments, do their shopping, drive them to church, do their foot care, provide some meals -weekly, assist with ecercising, house cleaning.  I do not want paid for this time but, if I can deduct mileage (20miles one way) and meals while transporting, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you're actually footing the bill, i.e. spending out of pocket to support an elderly relative, there may be a tax deduction.  However, to qualify for the tax deduction, it appears your relative would need to be classified as your dependent, and you'd need to provide a large portion of living expenses.  Refer to:

- [USA Today - Supporting a parent? Check for tax breaks](http://www.usatoday.com/money/perfi/columnist/block/2007-06-25-elder-parent-dependent_N.htm)
- [eHow - How to Take Tax Deductions for Elder Care](http://www.ehow.com/how_2273469_take-tax-deductions-elder-care.html)

In terms of where your relative lives; i.e. with you or not, [IRS Publication 501](http://www.irs.ustreas.gov/publications/p501/ar02.html) does have a "Special rule for parent" under the definition of "Qualifying Person":

> **Special rule for parent.**    If your
>   qualifying person is your father or
>   mother, you may be eligible to file as
>   head of household even if your father
>   or mother does not live with you.
>   However, you must be able to claim an
>   exemption for your father or mother.
>   Also, you must pay more than half the
>   cost of keeping up a home that was the
>   main home for the entire year for your
>   father or mother. You are keeping up a
>   main home for your father or mother if
>   you pay more than half the cost of
>   keeping your parent in a rest home or
>   home for the elderly.

So, it appears that for any relative *other than a parent*, the relative needs to actually be living with you in order for them to be claimed as your dependent, and thus for you to be eligible for a deduction (assuming other criteria has been met.)

In any case, if the expenses you're referring to are significant, it could be worth your while to consult with a professional.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a flexible spending account (FSA) at your employer?  If so, you may be able to use some of those funds to pay for elder-care.  Note I said *pay for*.  You can't pay yourself.  But if you paid a food preparation company, you might be able to use your FSA funds (generally pre-tax deductions) to pay for it.